# File System that is order sensitive

Tags: filesystems, shared-folders

Is there a file system that is unix compatible that is order sensitive?

For example the following 2 directory structures would be different.

```
a
b 
c
```

and

```
a
c
b
```

Comment: I'm wondering how would sorting look like in such filesystem...

Comment: What do you mean? Are those `a`, `b` `c` entries in the directory. Entries in a directory have no particular order, I'm not sure how you're envisaging the order to have any relevance. In what context?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If directories have no particular order feel free to either post to close or post an answer saying directories have no order.

Comment: By "order" do you mean the time at which the dirs were first created?

Answer (score 3):

Directories generally have no specific order. You can see what order there is (or the lack of it) with commands such as `ls -a --sort=none`, and `find . -maxdepth 1`

My Linux-based system with an ext4 filesystem maintains no particularly obvious order to entries in a directory. My Windows-based system with Cygwin appears to maintain directory entries in sorted alphanumeric order. I would imagine that other filesystems will manage items in their own specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems have no sense of order, because data is rarely written contiguously on a medium. If you create directory a, then b, then c, the only "order" here is the metadata about when these were created. Any order aside from that is imposed by the tool you use to read the data back (such as `ls -c` instead of `ls -r` or `ls`).

If you want to see the inode of a dir, you can see that with `ls -i`.

Otherwise, the lack of order is one of the reasons filesystems are used.

If you want an order-based filesystem, you could try using no filesystem at all. Writing raw data to a hard drive can be done with dd:

```
# echo "helloWorld" | dd of=/dev/sdX
# head -c{1..10} /dev/sdx
helloWorld#
```

That's raw, but you could essentially use your own conventions and invent your own ad hoc filesystem that demands order.